# SpriteKit: pros/cons of setting contactTestBitMask for both objects?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Assuming we want to monitor contacts between Node A and Node B, `didBeginContact` seems to fire correctly even if we set the `contactTestBitMask` on only one of the nodes. In other words, this code seems to work fine:

```
nodeA.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = NodeACategory

nodeB.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = NodeBCategory
nodeB.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = NodeACategory
```

Are there advantages to setting the contactTestBitMask on Node A as well? The code is more concise to only set the mask for one object, but are there drawbacks we're overlooking?

Comment: No. In certain circumstances you only need to be notified if object A is contacted instead of object B. Hence the option to have a contactBitMask for each object.

Comment: Great, can you post this as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In certain circumstances you only need to be notified if object A is contacted instead of object B. Hence the option to have a contactBitMask for each object.

Comment: Thanks! But isn't the only way to get notified through didBeginContact? Your answer suggests there's a way to subscribe to notifications on a specific object?

Comment: @Crashalot - Not what I meant to imply. If you set contact notification on both objects you get the same notification as if you set on only one. It's just how the structure works right now. Think of a light bulb with 2 switches both or just one can turn it on but one of the two switches can also turn on other bulbs.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't appear to make any difference.

From Apple's documentation:

> When two bodies share the same space, each body’s category mask is
>   tested against the other body’s contact mask by performing a logical
>   AND operation. If either comparison results in a nonzero value, an
>   SKPhysicsContact object is created and passed to the physics world’s
>   delegate. For best performance, only set bits in the contacts mask for
>   interactions you are interested in.

It doesn't appear to be possible for nodeA to contact nodeB without nodeB also contacting nodeA. So nodeA contacting nodeB; nodeB contacting nodeA and nodes A & B contacting each other are all considered to be exactly the same and an `SKPhysicsContact` object containing nodeA and nodeB will be passed to `didBeginContact`.

Note that this is very different to `collisionBitMask`, where nodeA can collide with, and be affected by, nodeB but nodeB can be completely unaffected.

Comment: Hmmm  is it me, or does this imply that all bodies are being tested,  I thought the point of the contactbitmask was to filter out needless tests

Comment: I don't think so - bodyA's contactTestBitMask might only specify bodyB's categorybitMask. bodyB's contactTestbitMask can be 0 (contacts nothing) and all contact between the 2 will result in a call to didBeginContact (all protocols, delegates etc being correct).

Comment: I am referring to the first part `When two bodies share the same space`, this would imply that that all bodies need to be tested to see if they share the same space, as opposed to only checking bodies of certain types with other bodies of the same type

Comment: I imagine that when it's drawing the sprites/physccsBodies, it will perform the AND operation for any sprite being drawn in contact with another sprite (this will be very fast in comparison to the drawing operation) and proceed from there if the result is 1. The AND probably takes less time than seeing if the contactTestBitMask is 0, which would mean the check doesn't need to be done (for that body).

Comment: Drawing is the very last step, so that can't be it. (You can actually move your sprite in the didBeginContact phase to change where it is drawn)  A fair test would be to have a stationary object with a contactbitmask to a movable object, but have the movable object not have a contactbitmask to the stationary, and see if a hit gets registered

Comment: Yes sorry - it'll be when the SpriteKit engine has worked out that 2 bodies will be be in contact after all is said and done, which I guess is sometime after didApplyConstraints. I'll try that test you mentioned later. But I think SpriteKit will have to check for contacts between all bodies in the same space and just ignore those for which the bit masks say it should.

Comment: I don't mean to debate you with this topic, it is that apple documentation that is in question, that is all.  Could be something to think about when developing something that has a lot of sprites overlapping, causing unexpected slowdown because the developer is thinking those evaluations should not be happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108537/discussion-between-steve-ives-and-knight0fdragon).

Comment: If I have two nodes of different categories. Are there any assumptions on which of the two is passed as nodeA and which as nodeB or is this just random ? In other words: How to test a collision of CatC with CatB ? Do I have only to check for (nodeA.catBitMask == CatC && nodeB.catBitMask == CatB) or in addition for (nodeA.catBitMask == CatB && nodeB.catBitMask == CatC) as well ?

Comment: @Chris No- you can’t assume which is which. I tend to AND the category bit masks if the 2 nodes together and then do a SWITCH for each pair of category contacts I’m Interested in.